# JQuery carousel and template doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, carousel

First of all, I'm sorry if this is already asked. I couldn't find a answer.

I have a HTML5 template bought at themeforest and a jQuery carousel. I am not very similar with JavaScript or JQuery. 
When I wanted to implement the carousel like it said in the description the JQuery/Javascript didn't work. 
I found out that it could be the version of JQuery. The template(cleanstart) uses version 1.11.2 and the carousel uses 1.44.4. When I changed the carousel to that version it didn't work. When I changed the template version to 1.44.4, it didn't work either.

Then I've put the text from the carousel.js in a script tag in the HTML, and that seemed to work but then the templates jQuery didn't work...

Do you have any idea what the problem can be? Maybe a variable with the same name? I really don't know how to solve it.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: It is not possible to answer without seeing any code or any reference. Post your code or any reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just this Information, It's pretty hard to help you. It could be a problem with your Implementation, a compatibility Issue or many things else.

Do you have a public page where the template and the carousel are implemented? Does the console window give you any error (if you don't have it yet, I recomend you to get Firefox and the addons Firebug and Webdeveloper Toolbar).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

i've set it online on a test page: www.drechtstedenautomatisering.nl

and the console gives me a few errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.
Uncaught type error: undefined is not a function
Uncaught reference error: Intervalprocess is not defined

Comment: So this is clearing up some things (:

the 404 errors about jquery-1.44.4.min.js, jquery.carousel-1.1.js is telling you, that those scripts don't get delivered by the server. Try to put them in wp-content/uploads for example. Also you are loading jquery-1.10.2.min.js as well as jquery-1.44.4.min.js, this could cause some problems. Please just load one of them.

Comment: The error `TypeError: carousel.mousewheel is not a function` tells you probably (I'm not sure about that, I'm only speculating) that you need the jQuery Mousewheel plugin (this one: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. it was a scroll section that causes the other jquery to stop. When I removed that part of the code, nothing bad with the carousel happened and the other parts worked fine!